# Keybord shortcut to select Windows Clipboard text to paste

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Is there any keyboard shortcut to move around your different texts in your Windows Clipboard?
Once you press Windows+V you can see the list but the cursor is still moving around your text and you have to select the past item to paste with the mouse. Can I do that without using the mouse?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After pressing Win+V, use arrow keys to choose a text fragment, and enter to paste it.  This works on Windows 10 build 19043 with setting "Clipboard History" enabled.

I do not experience the "cursor is still moving around your text" behavior you describe.  In what app does this seem to happen?

Comment: In all of them really. Even in that same Windows 10 build.

Comment: Cursors not working anymore in Win10/Win11. Hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: I have the same/similar problem. When I open the clipboard, other apps (like Google Chrome) may trap the focus. And I don't see a way to move focus to the clipboard. When switching between apps with the Alt + Tab, the clipboard is not shown as an option to move focus to.